# Joomla editor moves </a> tag

Tags: joomla3.0

Semi-novice web developer getting increasingly frustrated with my Joomla editor changing my code. I've research online and found Q&As that hint at a similar problem but I can't seem to figure this out.

Essentially it's code to create a linked image with a text caption added on hover. Desired code shown below:

```
<ul class="photo-grid">
<li>
<figure><a href="index.php?option=com_hikashop&amp;view=category&amp;layout=listing&amp;Itemid=179"><img src="images/purple-biothane-waterproof-dog-collars.jpg" alt="purple biothane waterproof dog collars" width="280" height="187" /><figcaption>
<p>Waterproof collars</p>
</figcaption></figure></a>
<p class="photocaption">FEATURED PRODUCT</p>
</li>
```

BUT each time I open the editor the `</a>` tag has been moved upwards, directly after the `<img>` tag. Can anyone offer a resolution, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `<a>` tag after `</figure>` but you have opened it within `<figure>` so therefore it needs closing inside `<figure>`. So use:

```
<ul class="photo-grid">
  <li>
    <figure>
      <a href="index.php?option=com_hikashop&amp;view=category&amp;layout=listing&amp;Ite‌​mid=179">
        <img src="images/purple-biothane-waterproof-dog-collars.jpg" alt="purple biothane waterproof dog collars" width="280" height="187" />
        <figcaption>
          <p>Waterproof collars</p>
        </figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <p class="photocaption">FEATURED PRODUCT</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks XWS. I am using JCE and have reviewed the profiles, but not too sure what settings need modification.

Comment: I've just read your post again, your code is missing the closing </a> after /> of the img tag.

Comment: I have included </a> but it's further down after I close the <figcaption> tag (which gives me the desired effect of a text display upon hovering over the image. It's that closing tag which gets moved, probably becuase I have a nested block element with the anchor tags (which I believe is a no-no). Is there a workaround you can suggest pls?

Comment: It's because you have missed it off. Sorry I was on my mobile earlier and missed it off (code view isn't responsive). You need:

<ul class="photo-grid">
<li>
<figure><a href="index.php?option=com_hikashop&amp;view=category&amp;layout=listing&amp;Itemid=179"><img src="images/purple-biothane-waterproof-dog-collars.jpg" alt="purple biothane waterproof dog collars" width="280" height="187" /><figcaption>
<p>Waterproof collars</p>
</figcaption></a></figure>
<p class="photocaption">FEATURED PRODUCT</p>
</li>

You can't close a tag outside of a tag you opened it in. I've updated the my answer now.